# MISSISSIPPI, MI, IM, and IMI

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements of the letters in MISSISSIPPI in which
(a) The M is followed (immediately) by an I?
(b) The M is beside an I—that is, an I is just before or just after the M.
For (a)
$$
\frac{10!}{3!*4!*2!} \tag{1}
$$
For (b):
For both MI and IM cases:
$$
2*\frac{10!}{3!*4!*2!} \tag{2}
$$
For IMI case:
$$
\frac{9!}{2!*2!*4!} \tag{3}
$$
To get answer for (b) we do $(2)-(3)$

Is my answer right?

Comment: Yes, your answers are correct.  You should explain your reasoning since that helps readers detect any errors you may have made.

Comment: Will make required edits. Thank you for taking a look.